# How do I get the error message from an HttpResponse object in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that generates an exception from the following code with the following message:-

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutABook(Book bookToSave)
{
   return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "No Permission");
}
```

am testing this method with the following code:-

```
var response = controller.PutABook(new Book());
Assert.That(response.StatusCode,Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden));
Assert.That(response.Content,Is.EqualTo("No Permission"));
```

But am getting an error that the content is not "No Permission".  It seems I can't cast the response to an `HttpError` either to get the message content "No Permission". The status code is returned fine. Just struggling to get the `message content`.

Comment: I seem to have some sort of solution to this now which is to use the response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>().Result to give me the message. Not sure if there is a better way though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you figured in your comment, you could either use `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>()` or you could also use `response.TryGetContentValue<HttpError>()`. 
In both these cases, the content is checked to see if its of type `ObjectContent` and the value is retrieved from it.

Comment: Ahh yes I hadn't tried the TryGetContentValue. Will give that a go too. Thanks :)

Comment: When I saw you mention TryGetContentValue I was puzzled because I had never seen that before and it isn't async.  Now I realize that it is only really useful for dealing with responses on the server before they have been transmitted over the wire.  I wonder how many people will try using that on the client and wonder why it never returns a valid result.

Comment: yeah...right...its useful only at the server...`TryGetContentValue` is present in `System.Web.Http` dll, so the clients shouldn't be seeing it in majority of the cases.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one. `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>().Result.Message;`

Comment: A bit necro-posty, but this gave the answer I needed in the most succinct form, thanks!

Comment: It would be better to await on the async for two reasons:
1. It opens up resources to be used to handle other requests while this is happening.
2. .Result is notorious for deadlock issues and it's really complicated to explain to a junior or intermediate dev when it is and isn't ok to use .Result, so general best practise is avoid at all costs.

As such Nikoloz's answer is better: var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>();

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>();
Assert.That(errorContent.Message,Is.EqualTo("No Permission"));
```

Answer (score 4):

**read error message this way.**

```
var ErrMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```